# Q-objects in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-q

How can I choose by what var value that I get by filter that then to append a value in the loop?

```
items = Item.objects.filter(Q(var__icontains=term) | Q(another_var__icontains=term))
res = []
for item in items:
    res.append({
        'val': item.(var or another_var?),
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you have to check `var`/`anohter_var` manually to find which variable is matched in the queryset.

```
items = Item.objects.filter(Q(var__icontains=term) |
                            Q(another_var__icontains=term))
uterm = term.upper()
res = []
for item in items:
    value = item.var if uterm in item.var.upper() else item.another_var
    res.append({'val': value})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it locally, or do two different queries.
First option:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(Q(var__icontains=term) | Q(another_var__icontains=term))
res = []
for item in items:
    if term.lower() in item.var.lower():
        v = item.var
    else:
        v = item.another_var
    res.append({
        'val': v,
    })
```

Second option, just do two queries (two filter calls).